# Sweet alert call after close

Tags: sweetalert

So I am using swal to display loading gif image and to display success/error message...

here is my code

```
function spinner() {
        swal({
          title: "<?=__('Please wait...')?>",
          imageUrl: "../img/loader.gif",
          showConfirmButton: false
        })
      }

      $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        //show spinner
        spinner();
      }).ajaxStop(function(){
        //hide spinner
        swal.close();
      });
```

So I am using this call only during ajax call is in progress, after I want to call spinner and open another swal pop-up.

```
.
.
.
function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
          {
            //Success
            $("#report-container-stand").modal( 'toggle' );
            swal("<?= __('Success!') ?>", "<?= __('Message has been successfully sent to your customer support') ?>", "success")
            // console.log('success');
          }
.
.
.
```

And this doesnt because after ajax call is done he closes spinner and the next one without clicking on confirmation button....

Does anybody know what is problem?